# NLog load configuration from both file and code

Tags: .net, logging, nlog

I'm using NLog 4.7.2. I would like to configure it from code. However, I would like to retain the possibility to modify logging configuration without having to restart my application. I know I could roll something on my own (for instance, a switch on the UI that would modify the appropiate rules and call `LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers()`) but I would like to take advantadge of the existing functionality of XML configuration file autoreload.

My intention is to make a default configuration in code and then if something pops up and I need to increase the logging level, I would modify the XML configuration file without restarting the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated answer**

If using a `NLog.config` like this:

```
<nlog autoreload="true" keepVariablesOnReload="true">
   <variable name="AppMinLevel" value="Warn" />
   <targets>
   </targets>
   <rules>
      <logger name="*" minLevel="${var:AppMinLevel}" writeTo="..." />
   </rules>
</nlog>
```

Then by referencing `${var:AppMinLevel}` in the logging-rule, then you can just update the NLog config variable like this:

```cs
NLog.LogManager.Variables["AppMinLevel"] = "Debug";
LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Filtering-log-messages#semi-dynamic-routing-rules

**Old Answer**

If using a `NLog.config` like this:

```
<nlog autoreload="true">
   <variable name="minlevel" value="Warn" />
</nlog>
```

Then perform initial setup of LoggingConfiguration like this:

```
SetupNLogConfig();
LogManager.ConfigurationReloaded += (sender, args) => {
   SetupNLogConfig();
}
```

And have SetupNLogConfig like this:

```
void SetupNLogConfig()
{
     var config = LogManager.Configuration ?? new NLog.Config.LoggingConfiguration();
     Layout minLevel = config.Variables["minlevel"] ?? "Warn";
     string minLevelString = minLevel.Render(LogEventInfo.CreateNullEvent());
     LogLevel minLevelValue = LogLevel.FromString(minLevelString);

     // Targets where to log to: File and Console
     var logfile = new NLog.Targets.FileTarget("logfile") { FileName = "file.txt" };
     var logconsole = new NLog.Targets.ConsoleTarget("logconsole");
        
     // Rules for mapping loggers to targets            
     config.AddRule(minLevelValue, LogLevel.Fatal, logconsole);
     config.AddRule(minLevelValue, LogLevel.Fatal, logfile);
        
     // Re-Apply config           
     NLog.LogManager.Configuration = config;
}
```

Then you can modify the `minlevel`-variable in `NLog.config` and it should re-configure with the updated value.

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configure-from-code#combine-nlogconfig-and-config-from-code

Comment: What I'm looking after is to add/modify/remove rules at runtime, not only change their level. My aim is that if I'm having problems with a certain module of my app I would like to increase the logging level for this particular part without restarting. And it would be very interesting not having to create a rule and a variable for each different logger I have just in case sometime in the future I might need to increase its loggin level, especially when NLog encourages having a different logger for each class, so if I were to create all rules beforehand it would be a lot of them.

Comment: @Jordi The normal logic is to implement default-config at runtime when NLog.config is not found. But you are welcome to create pull-request with your ideas for the NLog-project: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/ (Notice the `SetupBuilderExtensions`-methods)